# files and images outside html folder

Tags: php, file, centos, pci-compliance

I have moved website from one hosting to another and due to security, PCI and HIPPA reason, I need to move some (files and images) directories outside html folder.

Previous structure : `/public_html/uploads`

Current structure : `/var/www/uploads`

For Files : `/var/www/html/`

I want to know how I can handle uploaded images and images get to display on front page.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean HIPAA and PCI-DSS? If you cannot have them in the html folder, can you still serve them? have you considered [symbolic links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ln_(Unix)) for the image directories? or adding additional `<directory>` sections to your configuration?

Comment: @JoSSte yes I can't have them in html folder , and i am not aware of symbolic links , I will look for the sam e

Comment: I think your tag [tag:pci] is incorrect. that Tag refers to the hardware pci bus on a motherboard...

Answer (score 2):

You could use symbolic links e.g.:

in `/var/www/html` execute `ln -s /var/www/uploads image_uploads` then all your images can be referenced with `<img src="/image_uploads/some_image_name.jpg">`

Be aware than you may need to set alternative permissions in a `<Directory>` section in your site configuration (I am assuming that you are using Apache).

Something like

```
<Directory "/var/www/uploads">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
```

See the [Apache documentation for Directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using Apache , may you please advise me how can I set  alternative permissions in a <Directory>, like in which file .htaccess or any other

Comment: i would do it in the .conf file under /etc/apache2/ - I use ubuntu so my file would be under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`I am bot sure about centos